# Is there a way to bind qpid to a different IP other than localhost?

Tags: apache, binding, paas, qpid

I am just curious if there is a way to bind qpid to an IP such as 127.1.244.129

The reason I ask is I'm looking to deploy many instances to a PaaS and will need multiple running instances. This is not possible if everything tries to bind to localhost:8080.

Does anyone know of a wayt o configure this? I could not find in the qpid documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This question was crossed posted to the Qpid developer mailing list and was discussed [here](http://qpid.2158936.n2.nabble.com/Way-to-bind-qpid-to-a-different-IP-td7601994.html). For the benefit anyone else with the same question, I will summarise the answer here.

For Qpid CPP Broker, for release 0.20 and beyond, use the `--interface` argument to `qpidd`.

For Qpid Java Broker, for releases 0.22 and beyond, you can restrict the AMQP port to a particular interface by specifying a binding address attribute in the port's configuration. Use the Web Management Console to edit the AMQP port and specify a binding address.  Restart the Broker for the change to take effect. The [Java Broker docs](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.24/java-broker/book/Java-Broker-Ports.html#Java-Broker-Ports-Configuring) describes the process of editing a port.  It is currently not possible to specify a binding address for the ports used by HTTP or JMX Management, though these plugins can be disabled if desired.